# How to add multiple dropdown list on same page in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, html-select, mudblazor

I'm trying to insert same dropdown list multiple times in a single page.

I have an item X

I have a list of ProcessAreas (a,b,c,d,e)

I have a list of Instructions (1,2,3,4,5,6)

I need to create a form to associate to the X item a single instruction for every ProcessArea (not mandatory)

So, for example, for the item X1 I want to save to my database
`(a,1),(b,3),(e,6)`

Indicating that for item X1 i have instructions 1 for area a, instructions 3 for area b and instruction 6 for area e. The other areas are not used.

To do this I read all instructions previously inserted in db.

I do a foreach on ProcessAreas and create a dropdown list. Inside this dropdown I put the list of available instructions, like this

```
@foreach (var processArea in _availableProcessAreas)
{
    var label = "Select instructions for " + processArea.ProcessAreaName;
    var x = _model.ProcessAreaInstructions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessAreaId == processArea.ProcessAreaId)?.InstructionId;

    <MudSelect T="int?" Label=@label id="@processArea.ProcessAreaId" @bind-Value="x" For="@(() => x)">
        @foreach (var instruction in _instructions)
        {
            <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="@instruction.Id">(@instruction.Name) @instruction.Description</MudSelectItem>
        }
    </MudSelect>
}
```

I can see the dropdowns on page, but I cannot select a value different from the one is displayed.

Here you can find a full sample with this strange behavior

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYGxuWFEflpORBVt

Can you help me to fix this problem and to save updated data to database?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking for the codes you add in the MudBlazor Playground, I realized that you try to bind the value of the MudSelect to your local `int t = 0` razor variable.

So I added a field in your `ProcessAreaInstructionResponse`, to store the value of the MudSelect.

```
    public class ProcessAreaInstructionResponse
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int BindedValue { get; set; } = 1; // new field
    }

/////

<MudSelect T="int" Label=@item.Name id="@item.Id" @bind-Value="item.BindedValue">
   @foreach (var instruction in _instructions)
   {
      <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="@instruction.Id">@instruction.Description</MudSelectItem>
   }
</MudSelect>
```

And now it is working :)

Answer (score -3):

In Blazor, you can easily add multiple dropdown lists on the same page using components. Components in Blazor are reusable UI elements that can encapsulate their own logic and presentation. Here's how you can add multiple dropdown lists on the same page:

Create a Dropdown Component:
Create a new component for your dropdown list. Let's call it Dropdown.razor:

```
<select @bind="SelectedValue">
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Use the Dropdown Component in Your Page:
In your Blazor page (Index.razor for example), you can use the Dropdown component:

```
@page "/"

<h3>Dropdown Lists</h3>

<Dropdown Items="@Items1" SelectedValue="@SelectedValue1" />
<Dropdown Items="@Items2" SelectedValue="@SelectedValue2" />

@code {
    private List<string> Items1 = new List<string> { "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3" };
    private string SelectedValue1 { get; set; }

    private List<string> Items2 = new List<string> { "Choice A", "Choice B", "Choice C" };
    private string SelectedValue2 { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, you create a new instance of the Dropdown component for each dropdown list you want to display. You pass the list of items and the selected value to each instance of the component.

Each dropdown list maintains its own state independently. When the user selects an option in one dropdown, only that dropdown's selected value will be updated.

This approach allows you to encapsulate the dropdown logic and presentation in a reusable component, making your code more organized and maintainable.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I think there's people reviewing his recent answers as GPT generated answers. It seems like it to me too, although this is a good answer.

Comment: Aha.  Given the wording, I'd say that's extremely likely, probably more than 50%.  Is this code itself GPT generated?  Because I wouldn't be much bothered if someone translated their explanation due to problems with English.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Hard to say, although GPT does tend to generate example code with similar formatting and parameter naming.

Comment: Personally, if someone wants to "curate" a Chat-GPT answer, I don't mind too much-- so long as they check that it runs first, and probably they should indicate its source.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I mostly agree with that.  See my [Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710) for more details.   I also think this one is likely AI-assisted - We just have no way of knowing on an uncited copy/paste whether or not it was validated.  The vast majority, unfortunately, don't appear to be.

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem everywhere-- we're flooded with almost-good media copy, college essays, code and everything else.  The problem is that until models can actually read through entire MSDN docs, have situational awareness, run its own code in a sandbox to error check, and so on, it's mostly just going to be regurgitated GitHub projects and so on-- and who knows WHAT state the average Joe's projects are in?  The "good" (maybe terrible?) news is that AI models are about to be given access to sites like CodePen, and WILL be able to do these things soon.